# search in array by the first two letters of any word within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

using the following array, I want to search for the first letters assuming that there are several words in the same matrix, it must search in each word, if it finds it it should return in an array

example

```
const data= [ 
      "the lions of teranga",
      "tiger woods",
      "The Truman Show",
      "Shutter Island",
      "The Gold Rush",
  ]
]
```

if it matches "sh" it should search for each word and return

```
["Shutter Island", "The Truman Show"] but not The Gold Rush
```

if it matches "lions" it should search for each word and return

```
["the lions of teranga"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the solutions with combination of `forEach` and `RegEx`

```js
const data= [ 
      "the lions of teranga",
      "tiger woods",
      "The Truman Show",
      "Shutter Island",
      "The Gold Rush",
  ]
  
const filteredData = []


data.forEach(sentence => {
    let words = sentence.split(" ")
    words.forEach((word,index) => {
      if(word.match(/^lions?\w/gi)) {
        filteredData.push(sentence)
      }
    })
    
})

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: thanks @nedoder, it works, just one question, how can add a variable inside regex, i mean replace /^Sh\w/ by a variable

Comment: use `new RegExp("^Sh\\w", "i");` instead, you can then add variables to the string as you wish.  E.g. ``new RegExp(`^${query}\\w`, "i");``

Comment: @nedoder, for the first condition works but not for the second, with the word: lions

Comment: hi @fernando, I edited, just add ? and it works in both cases

Comment: @nedoder yes is working thanks, another question i am trying with variable like: if(word.match(new RegExp("/^"+searchBy+"?\w/gi"))) but no is working, do you know why?

Comment: In RegExp you need to escape \w like this @fernando
new RegExp("^"+searchBy+"?\\w", 'gi') 
Does it work now?

Comment: @nedoder thanks, yes and not, for example if i add senegal to the array, searching with "sh" show it, how can avoid that?

Comment: @fernando how about this? const regex =  new RegExp("^"+searchBy+".*", 'gi')

Answer (score 0):

```
const data= [ 
      "the lions of teranga",
      "tiger woods",
      "The Truman Show",
      "Shutter Island",
      "The Gold Rush",
  ]
inputData = "lions"
let a = data.filter(e => {
    str = e.toLowerCase()
    if (str.match(inputData.toLowerCase())){
        return e
    }
})
console.log(a)
```

Here filter returns the objects which are returned true. Here you can search by any word or character and return as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//your data array
const data= [ 
      "the lions of teranga",
      "tiger woods",
      "The Truman Show",
      "Shutter Island",
      "The Gold Rush",
  ];
    //your search letters,if it will be the same use const instead of var
    var search="sh";
    //make your search case insensitive
    search=search.toLowerCase()
    //use for loop to go through every sentence
    for(var counter=0;counter<data.length;counter++)
    {
       //get the array of words
       var arrayOfWords=data[counter].match(/\b(\w+)\b/g);
       
       //use for loop to go through every word
       for(var counter2=0;counter2<arrayOfWords.length;counter2++)
       {
          //make word case insensitive
          var tempWord=arrayOfWords[counter2].toLowerCase();
          //check if the search length does not exid your actuall word
          if(search.length<=tempWord.length)
          {
             //check if first letters match
             if(tempWord.slice(0,search.length==search)
             {
                //first letters match, you can put your logic here
             }
             else
             {
                //no match
             }
          }
          else
          {
             //search exids word
          }
       }
    }
```